# Any advice on this angular problem? Mosh tutorial not working for me?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

watching https://youtu.be/k5E2AVpwsko and made it to the 1:35:00 roughly time of adding the courses part. I ge the following error.
Failed to compile.

../src/app/app.component.html:2:1 - error NG8001: 'courses' is not a known element:

1. If 'courses' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. To allow any element add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component.

2

```
../src/app/app.component.ts:5:16
  5   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  Error occurs in the template of component AppComponent.

What am i missing? I tried debugging, but nothing. Any help is appreciated.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't declared courses component as part of app module. In declarations array, you need to give it. Also you could try the ng commands like ng g component courses from the app module directory in terminal, instead of creating it manually which automatically adds it to app module.

Comment: in my app.module.ts it has it declared as follows. Copy& pasted: @NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent, 
    CoursesComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
}) FINISHED: what could i be missing? I followed every step as he did it?

Answer (score 0):

You should delete the app component and use ng generate component courses .It will automatically add the component to your app module . It is easy and handy. You can also watch documentation of angular component which will be much helpful for your development

Comment: So i need to delete app.components.ts then on CL do ng generate courses.component.ts? I am unsure of the exact syntax?

Comment: yes.open your cli and then type - ng generate component courses .